# Display double in 2 decimal places in RPG?

Tags: rpgle, rpg

When declaring floating-point variable, I don't understand the amount of precision needed for the stored object in RPG ??

In my exercice, I enter the number of copies for example the value `5`.

[image]

The total amount is **0.50** euros but I have like message:

[image]

I don't understand how to declare the variable `total` correctly in double.

```
 H
 D NumberCopy      S              3S 0
 D Total           S              ???
  *
  /Free
    dsply 'Enter your copy number please : ' '' NumberCopy;

    If (NumberCopy < 11);
       Total = NumberCopy * 0.10;

    ElseIf (NumberCopy < 31);
       Total = (10 * 0.10) + (NumberCopy - 10) * 0.09;

    Else;
       Total = (10 * 0.10) + (20 * 0.09) + (NumberCopy - 30) * 0.08;

    EndIf;


    dsply ('The amount is of ' + %Char(Total) + ' euros');


    *inlr = *on;
  /End-Free
```

Here I find this on RPGPDM.

```
D Float1          S              8F
```

https://www.rpgpgm.com/2014/02/defining-variables-in-rpg-all-free.html

Comment: And as you are just starting to learn RPG why not learn **FREE RPG instead of a mix of fixed and free.

Instead of 

`D Float1          S              8F `

write

`dcl-s Float1 float(8);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to say it at the beginning of your exercise DONT USE FLOAT IN RPG. It will make you pretty unhappy. To answer your question: `dcl-s total float(8);` You have two problems with float:

1. You dont want your customers to get wrong invoices due to accuracy problems like in 1990.
2. Decimals are able too use hardware support to evaluate faster which isn't "important" but a nice to have.

If you wanna display a float you can do something like that

```
dcl-s outputString char(10) inz;
dcl-s total float(8) inz (5);

outputString = %char(%dec(total: 10: 2));
dsply outputString;
```

Some hints:

- Don't use /free or /end-free the compiler is able to acknowledge tht on its own.
- Don't use fixed format declarations to define your fields. They are harder to read and there is no actual reason to use them.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared Float1 as a "double". But the problem is that floating point numbers are not a good choice for fixed decimal precision numbers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems .

You should use packed or zoned if you are working with numbers where correct precision is needed and not just some approximation.